# How to install Orocrm in centos 7

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I installed php,nodejs and i downloaded orocrm file in official website and installed it by using composer.  Can Any give me the permissions isues of centos 7 or **Please give me the Step by Step installation of OROCRM in centos 7**

Comment: What have you tried and what are your exact problems? SO is not the place for general installation issues

Comment: I'd guess the OroCrm homepage should have installation instructions.

Comment: Before posting your next question you should go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

This is official installation documentation - https://oroinc.com/doc/orocrm/current/install-upgrade/installation-quick-start-dev/crm

I suggest you to use https://github.com/oroinc/crm-application repository as it simplifies initial project setup and configuration.